# How do we store and pass list of selected values form Mat-Check box selected rows into another Router Service

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am very new to the angular and I have a component which has a mat-table with checkboxes using SelectionModel. Below is the Component and HTML code.

I have to pass the array of selection Emploee_number values into another EmployeeDetails Router service to display the detailed employee information.

Please help me how to store all the selected emploee_numbers into array and pass the values into another router service.

### Component Code

```
import { SelectionModel } from "@angular/cdk/collections";
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ViewChild, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { MatPaginator } from "@angular/material/paginator";
import { MatSort } from "@angular/material/sort";
import { MatTableDataSource } from "@angular/material/table";
import { EmployeeTableService } from "src/app/Services/employers.service";

export interface EmployersData {
  Employee_name: string;
  Employee_number: string;
  start_date_active: string;
  end_date_active: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: "employers",
  styleUrls: ["./employers.css"],
  templateUrl: "./employers.html",
})

export class Employees implements AfterViewInit {
  displayedColumns: string[] = [
    "select",
    "Employee_name",
    "Employee_number",
    "start_date_active",
    "end_date_active
  ];
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<EmployeesData>;
  selection = new SelectionModel<EmployeesData>(true, []);

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  constructor(
    private EmployeeTableService: EmployeeTableService 
  ) {}

  isAllSelected() {
    const numSelected = this.selection.selected.length;
    const numRows = this.dataSource.data.length;
    return numSelected === numRows;
  }

  masterToggle() {
    this.isAllSelected()
      ? this.selection.clear()
      : this.dataSource.data.forEach((row) => this.selection.select(row));
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
     this.retrieveEmployees();
  }

  applyFilter(event: Event) {
    const filterValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();

    if (this.dataSource.paginator) {
      this.dataSource.paginator.firstPage();
    }
  }

  retrieveSuppliers(): void {
    this.EmployeeTableService.getEmployees().subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data);
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
        console.log("Data Successfully Retrived");
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

### HTML code

```
<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="select">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
        <mat-checkbox (change)="$event ? masterToggle() : null"
                      [checked]="selection.hasValue() && isAllSelected()"
                      [indeterminate]="selection.hasValue() && !isAllSelected()">
        </mat-checkbox>
      </th>

    <td mat-cell *matCellDef = "let row">
      <mat-checkbox (click)= "$event.stopPropagation()"
                     (change) = "$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null"
                     [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)">
      </mat-checkbox>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="Employee_name">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Employee Name </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.Employee_name}} </td>
      </ng-container>
  
      <ng-container matColumnDef="Employee_number">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Vendor Number </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.Employee_number}} </td>
      </ng-container>
  
      <ng-container matColumnDef="start_date_active">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> End Date Active </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.start_date_active}} </td>
      </ng-container>
      
      
      <ng-container matColumnDef="end_date_active">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> End Date Active </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.end_date_active}} </td>
      </ng-container>  
      
           </table>
           
    </div>
```

Employers table Service

```
     import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
     import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
     import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
     import { map, publishReplay, refCount } from 'rxjs/operators';

     import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
     const baseUrl = environment.BACKEND_URL;

     export interface EmployersData {
     employee_name: string;
     employee_number: string;
     start_date_active: string;
     end_date_active: string;
        }

       @Injectable({
       providedIn: 'root'
        })

     export class EmployersTablesService {

     employersData: Observable<EmployersData[]>;

     constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

      getEmployers() {
        if (!this.employersData) {
      this.employersData = this.http.get(`${baseUrl}/employers`).pipe(
          map((data:any) => data.data),
          publishReplay(1),
          refCount()
          );
       }
     return this.employersData;
       }

       }
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that on each checking of an Employee we run `masterToggle()` and we store checked Employees using `this.dataSource.data.forEach((row) => this.selection.select(row));` into `selection`.

I don't see class or interface for EmployeesData so I don't know exactly what it's data structure is like, so be ready to refactor a little bit. Also I don't know what `EmployeeTableService` does but we're going to use that as medium to share data. from `ArchSuppliers -> EmployeeTableService -> EmployeeDetails`.

Let's take `Employee_number`'s from all selected items and send it to

```js
masterToggle() {
    this.isAllSelected()
      ? this.selection.clear()
      : this.dataSource.data.forEach((row) => this.selection.select(row));
this.sendEmployeeNumbers();
  }

sendEmployeeNumbers() {
  let selectedEmployeeNumbers = [];
    for (let employee of this.selection) {
      selectedEmployeeNumbers.push(employee.Employee_number)
    }
 this.EmployeeTableService.selectedEmployeeNumbers.next(selectedEmployeeNumbers);
}
```

To your EmployeeTableService add an observer that receives an array of selectedEmployeeNumbers and emits this to all subscribers

```js
selectedEmployeeNumbers = new ReplaySubject<number[]>(1);
```

And subscribe to that data on `EmployeeDetails`

```js
this.selectedEmployeeNumbers$ = this.EmployeeTableService.selectedEmployeeNumbers.pipe(data => {return data;})
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply Joosep ! I have updated the EmplyersTableService code to the original post. We are using the Router services to get the data from postgres. To make it generic , I have used Employers and employee scenario. Sorry for my typos.   I will implement your solution and update the post..

Comment: import { ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs/internal/ReplaySubject';
        selectedEmployeeNumbers.push(employee.Employee_number)


I am getting below error after implementing this code..

Property 'push' does not exist on type 'ReplaySubject<number[]>'.ts(2339)

Comment: If you don't have push() then you might be running an older version of ES. If possible you upgrade ES version to something newer in tsconfig.json under compilerOptions, like es2017 for example.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rmqg54-fk5mfa?devtoolsheight=33&file=app/table-selection-example.ts

Comment: Header change event not firing when we select the individual row check boxes.         


         <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
        <mat-checkbox (change)="$event ? masterToggle() : null"
                      [checked]="selection.hasValue() && isAllSelected()"
                      [indeterminate]="selection.hasValue() && !isAllSelected()">
        </mat-checkbox>
      </th>


I have edited below Stackblitz existing project for reference 

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rmqg54-fk5mfa?devtoolsheight=33&file=app/table-selection-example.ts

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rmqg54-hzg71t?devtoolsheight=33&file=app%2Ftable-selection-example.ts